# cloning/copying UIElement in silverlight

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-5.0

Can anybody tell me how to **clone UIElement in SILVERLIGHT** ? I dug a lot in the google but I'm not able to find relevant solution, everywhere I'm just getting solution to clone UIElement in WPF, however same is not applicable in the Silverlight.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no way to do that except handling each type explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

One way that I've found is to serialize to XML with `XamlWriter` then-reload the XML with `XamlReader` into a new element.

For an example see http://shrinandvyas.blogspot.ca/2011/08/wpf-how-to-deep-copy-wpf-object-eg.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but XamlWriter doesn't exists in the Silverlight, it do in WPF. As i already mentioned in my question I want to clone UIElement in Silverlight not WPF.